# Tensorflow Lite model in wrong output format how to use in Google ML Kit?

Tags: android, kotlin, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, google-mlkit

I want to use cameraX to detect live stream to accomplish object detection, so I use ML Kit .

I'm failed to put image into my model.

my model's

inputs:

- Type : Image<float32>
- shape: [1,640,640,3]
- Min/Max :[-1] / [1]

outputs:

- Type : BoundingBox<float32>
- shape: [1,9,8400]
- Min/Max :[] / []

[mlkit expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSfWe.png)

below is my error message and related code:

```
Pass image to an ML Kit failed:                                                                                                com.google.mlkit.common.MlKitException: Failed to initialize detector. Unexpected number of dimensions for output index 0: got 3D, expected either 2D (BxN with B=1) or 4D (BxHxWxN with B1, W=1, H=1).
```

```
val customObjectDetectorOptions =
    CustomObjectDetectorOptions.Builder(localModel)
        .setDetectorMode(CustomObjectDetectorOptions.STREAM_MODE)
        .enableClassification()
        .setClassificationConfidenceThreshold(0.5f)
        .setMaxPerObjectLabelCount(3)
        .build()

val objectDetector =
    ObjectDetection.getClient(customObjectDetectorOptions)
```

```
 private class ImageAnalyzer : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
        @OptIn(ExperimentalGetImage::class) override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
        //@OptIn(ExperimentalGetImage::class) override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {

            val mediaImage = imageProxy.image
            if (mediaImage != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "mediaImage != null: succeed")
               
                val image = InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)

         
                // Pass image to an ML Kit Vision API
                objectDetector.process(image)
                    .addOnSuccessListener { ...}
```

I guess I need to transform my model's  output shape from (1,9,8400) to 2D or 4D dimension,but I have no idea how to do . Hope someone can help me!!!